# How to set wkhtmltopdf options in ASP.NET Core 3.1 MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, wkhtmltopdf

I am trying to generate a custom PDF using wkhtmltopdf with ASP.NET Core 3.1, here are the docs: https://wkhtmltopdf.org/usage/wkhtmltopdf.txt

My main problem is: how and where should I put those options? Inside cshtml? Inside a controller? Where?

I cannot find documentation over the internet how to use it in ASP.NET Core MVC.

This is my code that is working ok:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PDF(int? id)
{
        if(id == null)
        {
            return StatusCode(400);
        }

        var comanda = _comandasRepository.Get((int)id);

        if(comanda == null)
        {
            return StatusCode(404);
        }

        return await _generatePdf.GetPdf("Views/Comandas/PDF.cshtml", comanda);
}
```

This generates a PDF:

[image]

But if you notice that PDF has margins, I want to remove these margins. I found in the docs that I have to use `--margin-top 0` but I do not know where to put it to make it work.

I tried:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PDF(int? id)
{
    if(id == null)
    {
        return StatusCode(400);
    }

    var comanda = _comandasRepository.Get((int)id);

    if(comanda == null)
    {
        return StatusCode(404);
    }

    return await _generatePdf.GetPdf("--margin-top 0 Views/Comandas/PDF.cshtml", comanda);
}
```

but does not work, and I tried to put it in a plain html inside cshtml code and didn't work either. My issue looks so simple but I cannot make this work, how do I solve this?

Comment: Just as a side-note. `return StatusCode(400);`->[`return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode) or even just [`return BadRequest();`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.badrequest)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My main problem is: how and where should I put those options? Inside
> cshtml? Inside a controller? Where?

Your shared document is used to teach you how to use command line to do some operation with your pdf.It does not used to work in code behind.

> But if you notice that PDF has margins, I want to remove these
> margins. I found in the docs that I have to use --margin-top 0 but I
> do not know where to put it to make it work.

You need add the margins by creating **ConvertOptions** instance:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PDF(int? id)
{
    var options = new ConvertOptions
    {
        PageMargins = new Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore.Options.Margins()
        {
            Top=0
        }
    };

    _generatePdf.SetConvertOptions(options);

    var comanda = _comandasRepository.Get((int)id);

    var pdf = await _generatePdf.GetByteArray("Views/Comandas/PDF.cshtml", comanda);

    var pdfStream = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
    pdfStream.Write(pdf, 0, pdf.Length);
    pdfStream.Position = 0;
    return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
}
```

More detailed usage you could download the example code on github:

https://github.com/fpanaccia/Wkhtmltopdf.NetCore.Example

Comment: I have isseus with area views path. Its not working with area views